# Gerrit server giving Gateway timeout

Tags: timeout, gerrit

I have Gerrit installed on a Linux server port for GIT code review. In GIT i have several repositories out of which one repository is having large data size (Around 30GB in multiple branches).

Now whenever i try to view objects using "GITWEB" option in Gerrit, it takes around 30sec time and then throws GATEWAY TIMEOUT ERROR.

I tried deleting few old branches to free up some space but it didn't give me any solution.

Please suggest, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can increase the amount of gerrit's Java memory.

```
ex) /gerritInstallDir/etc/gerrit.config
...
[container]
javaOptions = -server -Xms4096M -Xmx4096M
...
```

Second, The size of the storage should be reduced.

```
ex) remove binary file in repository.
```

Comment: What do you mean by Java memory and in place of -server, do we need to giver server IP?

Comment: No ip addr. Just fill out the above details. You just edit number(4096)